# Media items not appearing on website after deployment

Tags: media-library, tds

We are facing an issue with media library  during our deployment using Octopus. We have a publish site step in the deployment steps. The issue is media items are not showing in the website after the deployment. But once we go to that environment and republish the same, we are able to see the images. So after the deployment, when I checked the web database, I could see that the Media Item is there but no image is present in that.

Is this known issue or any steps to fix this.

Comment: What in Sitecore tool are you using to receive the publish command? Are there any relevant logs during the time of the publish?

Comment: @DanSinclair - we are doing the publish as a deploy step in Octopus.and this is the tool which we are using Fortiscollections.toolcore.publish.runner

Comment: What kind of manual publish are you doing when it fixes the issue? We had the same problem (not specifically limited to Media, however), and reported an issue on that tool, but it's not been resolved yet: https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/Toolcore/issues/4